# Detecting stock manipulation

Tags: regression, time-series, descriptive-statistics

Lets say that A is a stock and I have some suspicious that the price of A is being manipulated.

I can see in a stock graph that during the first 15 days of each month the stock price goes down and during the last 15 days the stock prices goes up.

What is the best way to prof that someone is manipulating the price and how can I measure this?

I was thinking of doing something like this:

- Let's say $y_{i,j}$ is the return of i=the year-month and j={1,2,3,4} where 1 is the first part of the month 2 is the second... and 4 is the last part of the month.
- Let's say $x_{i,j}$ are dummies variables

I was thinking of doing some regression and try to see the F value and the t value for each x variables.

Is there a better way of doing this? The stock doesn't quote every day, that is why I divide the month in 4 periods (I was thinking of doing this also with only 2 periods)

Answer (score 2):

Price manipulation could take all sorts of forms and so it's hard to think of a general approach to detecting it. But, you already observed something suspicious, which is that "during the first 15 days of each month the stock price goes down and during the last 15 days the stock prices goes up". Why not check whether that's true for any other stocks in the same period? I'm guessing it isn't. If you sample several thousand other stocks and find that none of them exhibit this peculiarly regular pattern of falling every day in the first half of each month and rising every day in the second half of each month, then you have good evidence that something weird is going on with this stock, even if it's not specific evidence of malfeasance.

Comment: Yes, my idea was to check it with 6 stock that I have strong suspicious that someone is manipulating their price and then check it with the rest of stocks, but I have some doubts about how to proceed and how can I measere it.